# Can you see anything wrong in this code? 'Cause I can’t, but it still doesn’t work

Tags: objective-c, crash, uipickerview

```
// When row is selected
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerTimer didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {   
    int minutes;
    int seconds;

    if (component == 0) {
        if (row < 0){
            minutes = row;
        } else {
            minutes = 0;
        }
    }
    if (component == 1) {
        if (row < 0){
            seconds = row;
        } else {
            seconds = 0;
        }
    }
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f %f %d", minutes, seconds, row]);
    if (minutes != 0 && seconds != 0){
        [buttonTimer setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ minutes and %@ seconds", minutes, seconds] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    // Yes, I am trying to set the label of a button.
    }
    if (minutes == 0 && seconds != 0){
        [buttonTimer setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ seconds", seconds] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    if (minutes != 0 && seconds == 0){
        [buttonTimer setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ minutes", minutes] forState:UIControlStateNormal];    
    }
    if (minutes == 0 && seconds == 0){
        [buttonTimerFarts setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Set time before play starts..."] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

}
```

The console will display things such as

`0.000000 -1.993950 2751746`

The three first if(minutes seconds) statements, never runs.

So, can you see anything wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, only if `row < 0`, `minutes` or `seconds` is set to `row`. But in your example, `row` is positive, so `minutes` and `seconds` are still both `0`, and the first three ifs are never true.

And I don't know much about Objective-C, but you're printing an integer with %f, and that might give you nonsense.